# Youtube API ClientLogin password with special character

Tags: youtube-api

I got `Error=Unkown` when password has a dollar sign. I've already encode the "$" to "%24"

say I have an account with:

```
username: test@gmail.com
password: testpwd$

curl --location https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin --data 'Email=test@gmail.com&Passwd=testpwd%24&service=youtube&source=test' --header 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Can you advise me how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[ClientLogin is not a supported Authentication](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html). Please switch to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).